# Best practice for monitoring internal dynamics of a Monix app

Tags: scala, observable, monix

I'm in the process of developing a monix-based app. The computation pipeline gets pretty complicated. I wonder what's the best approach to get insights of what's happening during the runtime? Ideally, visualize the tree of observables annotated with rates and latencies of events passing through. But even basic guidance/examples would help.

Comment: I have thought about something similar. I don't think it exists yet.